# How to update the scope from inside a resolve method?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I'm trying to clear an input after a message is sent in my chat system but the scope doesn't want to update. Setting it inside an `$apply`, `$digest` or `$timeout` does not work because a digest cycle is already in motion.

Here is the function:

```
$scope.sendMessage = function(chat, newMessage) {

    var messageObj = {
        by: $scope.uuid,
        message: newMessage,
        timestamp: Date.now()
    }

    fbCrud.push('chats/' + chat.$id + '/history', messageObj)
        .then(function() {
            newMessage = '';
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
            setStatus(false, 'Unable to send message', true);
    });
};
```

This is my textarea:

```
<textarea ng-enter="sendMessage(chat, newMessage)" ng-model="newMessage"></textarea>
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Where exactly are you trying to update scope? newMessage isn't bound on scope, it looks like a normal variable

Comment: Show your HTML for input.

Comment: @dfsq Updated question.

Comment: It should be `$scope.newMessage = '';`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new messageObject in your scope:

```
$scope.msgObject = {};
```

In you HTML, bind input to a property within this new object

```
<input type="text" ng-model="msgObject.message">
```

In your sendMessage function, instead of using parameter, use the message from the $scope.msgObject

Finally in the 'then' function clear your `$scope.msgObject.message`. Because of binding your html input field will also clear.

Answer (score 0):

In side your `then`, you use:

```
.then(function() {
    newMessage = '';
})
```

Here `newMessage` is a local variable **inside** the anonymous `then` function. You need to set the scope value, say `$scope.message`, to `''` if you use `<input ng-bind="message">`